# Print all substrings, no matter how many there are. Python

Tags: python, list, printing

So i have this code where i'm creating a list with substrings:

```
string = "|01|12345|TEXT1|TEXT2|"

x = string.count("|")

if string.count('|') == 3:

    subst = string.strip('|').split('|')

    print(substr)

else:

    substr = string.strip('|').split('|')

    print(substr)
```

Outcome:

```
['01', '12345', 'TEXT1', 'TEXT2']
```

However, i want to print all the substrings so that the outcome is this:

```
[LAS|01|G12345|TEXT1|TEXT2|]
```

I know i can just do:

```
print("[LAS|" + substr[0] + "|G" + substr[1] + "|" + substr[2] + "|" + substr[3])
```

But this is hardcoded, what if my the string that i get makes way more substrings? I do not want to use allot of if statements, if the count of ('|') == 4, == 5, == 6 etc.

How do i make sure that what i print contains all the substrings. And has a pipe symbol (|) in between every substring.

Thanks,

Comment: what is this `<CR>`  and where it came from?

Comment: Deadshot, it is nothing really. Doesn't have to do anything with the question.But i understand the confusion. I edited the question to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
print("[LAS|%s|]" % "|".join(substr))
```

The `"|".join(substr)` takes all the pieces in `substr` and joins them with the `|` separator.

If you need the extra "G", you'll need to treat the first one or two elements separately:

```py
print("[LAS|%s|G%s|]" % (substr[0], "|".join(substr[1:]))
```

or

```py
print("[LAS|%s|G%s|%s|]" % (substr[0], substr[1], "|".join(substr[2:]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
string = '|01|12345|TEXT1|TEXT2|'

substr = string.strip('|').split('|')

if len(substr) != 3:  # If you already have used split better to check the length than counting
    substr.insert(0, '[LAS')
    substr[2] = 'G' + substr[2]
    substr.append("]")

print("|".join(substr))  # [LAS|01|G12345|TEXT1|TEXT2|]
```